# Circular reference issue in webapi2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

**Scenario:**

An Intern can learn multiple technologies

**db design**

[image]

**ef view**

[image]

**Result**

[image]

controller code:

```
 private InternEntities db = new InternEntities();

    // GET: api/Interns
    public IQueryable<Intern> GetInterns()
    {
        return db.Interns;
    }
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected error, and the reason is because your types reference each other like an `Infinity Mirror`. In order to solve the problem, you have several options.

1- You can develop a `ViewModel` and then serialize that one:

```
public class InternViewModel{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public String Name {get; set;}
    public List<String> Tehcnologies {get; set;}
}
```

2- You can select the properties that you need when returning the entity in your actions:

```
public async Task<List<Technology>> Get() {
    var data = dbContext.Set<Technology>().Select(x=> new Technology{
        Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name,
        Intern= new Intern {
             Id = x.Technology.Id,
             Name = x.Technology.Name,
             Technologies = null
        }
    });
    return await data.ToListAsync();
}
```

3- Load only the what you need which is known as `Explicit Loading`.